# Kiel oni tradukas „blurb“?

Tags: single-word-requests

Temas pri la teksto, kiu troviĝas sur la malantaŭa kovrilo de libro. Ĉu ekzistas ĝusta vorto por tio en Esperanto? Mi ne sukcesis trovi tian en PIV kaj ReVo.

Comment: Dorsteksto?    :-)

Answer (score 7):

Mi laboris dum 40 jaroj en esperantlingva presejo, kaj ni ĉiam nomis tion „dorskovrila teksto”. Alian vorton mi ne konas.

Answer (score 0):

> Resumo: Mallongigo de io pli longe dirita. http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sum.html#sum.re0o
>
> Blurb = a brief advertisement or announcement, especially a laudatory one. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blurb

Vi povas diri **teksta reklamo** aŭ **resumo**.